# Which solution is better for sharing video : Pop up or tab?

Tags: video, sharing

I am talking Youtube style's Tab versus Vimeo style's pop up.
What are the pro / con for each options.

Also, for pop-up, is it a bad idea to pause a video during pop up ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I just see after clicking on **Share** in 13" macbook.

[image]

Major part is not [above the fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Above_the_fold) so most users may be unware of sharing at least few seconds.

In case of vimeo, we don't have that kind of problem. But

1. The primary problem is with this idea that you get to decide what the user should be doing right now. The popup breaks users's [flow as a state of mind](http://www.integralvision.net.au/share-it-hub/flow_the_psychology_of_optimal_experience.pdf). We should strive to create experiences that make people feel great, whatever they're doing.
2. A popup draws a user's attention away from the page and makes them pay attention to the popup too much that user may end up thinking it is **very important** action (which actually may not be).

   Yes It is good idea idea to pause video since popups are meant to draw attention completely to perform certain actions.

[image]

I see both options have own drawbacks however I'd like to see some improvements in sharing of youtube video. It'd be better to make sure that the Share card appear above the folder after hitting share button.

Thank You :)